# ggplot2: Can you acess the .data argument in subsequent layers?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have multiple graphs I'm generating with a data set. I preform many operations on the data (filtering rows, aggregating rows, calculations over columns, etc.) before passing on the result to `ggplot()`. I want to access the data I passed on to `ggplot()` in subsequent ggplot layers and facets so I can have more control over the resulting graph and to include some characteristics of the data in the plot itself, like for example the number of observations.

Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(tidyverse)

cars <- mtcars

# Normal scatter plot
cars %>% 
    filter(
        # Many complicated operations
    ) %>% 
    group_by(
        # More complicated operations
        across()
    ) %>% 
    summarise(
         # Even more complicated operations
        n = n()
    ) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = qsec)) +
    geom_point() +
    
    # Join the dots but only if mpg < 20 
    geom_line(data = .data %>% filter(mpg < 20)) +
    
    # Include the total number of observations in the graph
    labs(caption = paste("N. obs =", NROW(.data)))
```

one could of course create a a separate data set before passing that onto `ggplot` and then reference that data set throughout (as in the example bellow). However, this is much more cumbersome as you need to save (and later remove) a data set for each graph and run two separate commands for just one graph.

I want to know if there is something that can be done that's more akin to the first example using `.data` (which obviously doesn't actually work).

```
library(tidyverse)

cars <- mtcars

tmp <- cars %>% 
    filter(
        # Many complicated operations
    ) %>% 
    group_by(
        # More complicated operations
        across()
    ) %>% 
    summarise(
         # Even more complicated operations
        n = n()
    )

tmp %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = qsec)) +
    geom_point() +
    
    # Join the dots but only if mpg < 20 
    geom_line(data = tmp %>% filter(mpg < 20)) +
    
    # Include the total number of observations in the graph
    labs(caption = paste("N. obs =", NROW(tmp)))
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can use `geom_line(data = . %>% filter(mpg < 20)) +` for the first situation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the help page for each `geom_` it helpfully gives a standard way:

> A function will be called with a single argument, the plot data. The return value must be a data.frame, and will be used as the layer data. A function can be created from a formula (e.g. ~ head(.x, 10)).

For `labs` on the other hand you can use the `.` placeholders in piping, but you have to a) give the `.` as the data argument in the first place and b) wrap the whole thing in curly braces to recognise the later `.`.

So for example:

```r
library(tidyverse)

cars <- mtcars

# Normal scatter plot
cars %>%
  filter() %>%
  group_by(across()) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  {
    ggplot(., aes(x = mpg, y = qsec)) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_line(data = ~ filter(.x, mpg < 20)) +
      labs(caption = paste("N. obs =", NROW(.)))
  }
```

[image]

Or if you don't like the `purrr` formula syntax, then the flashy new R anonymous functions work too:

```
geom_line(data = \(x) filter(x, mpg < 20)) +
```

Unfortunately the `labs` function doesn't seem to have an explicit way of testing whether data is shuffling invisibly through the `ggplot` stack as by-and-large it usually can get on with its job without touching the main data. These are some ways around this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Note to all reading this in future the key is in using `{}` in combination with `%>%`. Not really a `ggplot` feature so much as a `magittr` one.